# Sobrepor um cursor em duas divs

Tags: javascript

Chamo uma função 2 vezes, para criar uma div e um cursor com duas linhas (horizontal e vertical). Queria que essas duas linhas funcionassem nas duas div criadas dinamicamente. Apenas está a funcionar numa div.

```js
var count = 1;

f(); //call function
f();

function f(){
    //************create div************
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id="div"+count;
    div.style.width = "300px";
    div.style.height ="300px";
    div.style.border = "1px solid #000";
    div.style.background = "red";
    div.style.cssFloat="left";
    //div.style.padding="10px 10px";
    //div.style.position = "absolute";
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    
    //************create div mouse vertical ************
    var div_v = document.createElement("div");
    div_v.style.position = "absolute";
    div_v.style.borderLeft = " 1px solid black";
    div_v.style.height = "300px";
    div_v.className="cursor-v"+count;
    
    //************create div mousse horizontal ************
    var div_h = document.createElement("div");
    div_h.style.position = "absolute";
    div_h.style.borderTop = " 1px solid black";
    div_h.style.width = "300px";
    div_h.className="cursor-h"+count;
    
    document.getElementById("cursor").appendChild(div_h);
    
    document.getElementById("cursor").appendChild(div_v);
    
    var v = document.querySelector('.cursor-v'+count);
    var h = document.querySelector('.cursor-h'+count);
    var elBox = document.querySelector('.cursor').getBoundingClientRect();
    
    window.onmousemove = function(e) {
        var mouseX = e.clientX - elBox.left;
        var mouseY = e.clientY - elBox.top;
        
        h.style.top = mouseY + 'px';
        v.style.left = mouseX + 'px';
        v.style.visibility = "visible";
        h.style.visibility = "visible";
        
        //if(mouseX>300 || mouseY>300){
            //v.style.visibility = "hidden";
            //h.style.visibility = "hidden";
        //}
       
    };
count++;
}
```

```html
<div id="cursor" class="cursor"></div>
```

Exemplo jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5dnr0era/9/

Answer (score 1):

Se deslocar o div "cursor", verá que apenas o primeiro par de cursores está se movendo, o segundo está parado onde foi criado. Isso ocorre pois na função onmousemove voce utiliza as variáveis h e v, que sao reaproveitadas quando cria a segunda div.

A solução completa seria um pouco complexa, pois precisa criar variáveis h e v únicas para cada div interna, identificar em qual das div o mouse está em cima, e atualizar os cursores correspondentes dependendo o caso.

Para o efeito que deseja, se entendi bem, uma solução simples seria criar os cursores separadamente da criação das div internas (uma função f chamada duas vezes e outra c chamada uma vez, por exemplo). Aí basta corrigir o tamanho do div horizontal:

```
div_h.style.width = "600px";
```

(Apenas modificando esta linha tambem produz o mesmo efeito, a diferença é que nao ficam 2 cursores 'mortos' no canto).

Caso isto seja apenas um exemplo e pretende construir uma página mais complexa, sugiro investigar algumas bibliotecas de javascript para facilitar o trabalho, como jQuery e D3.js.